# Bootstrap Radio Buttons in React - Not Showing Loaded Value

Tags: reactjs, forms, bootstrap-5

I have some radio buttons which are setting the rate type that I use with clients. This works as far as choosing one, and it sets that value.  However, the next time I load this data, it does not render the button that was previously chosen as selected.  It looks to me like I have it setup exactly the same way as I have it working in other code.  So I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't seem to find it.

Once I click the buttons, they do render the correct one as selected and change the value in the database as expected.  But as I said, when I load this again, it does bring in the data and set the state with the correct value through the function `getRateType()`.

It just doesn't show which button is selected.  My assumption is it's something to do with that I set the state initially to "", but why doesn't it update when I change the state to the correct value?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Form, Modal, Button, Jumbotron, Table} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { config } from '../../Config/Constants';
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

const API_URL = config.url.API_URL;

class Project extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            rateType: ""
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getRateType(this.props.billProjId);
    }

    getRateType = (projId) => {
        fetch(API_URL + `/billingcalculator/projects/${projId}`)
            .then((res) => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error()
                }
                return res.json()
            })
            .then((result) => {
                this.setState({ rateType: result[0].project_type });
                console.log(this.state.rateType); <-- this shows the correct value
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    handleCheck = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value },
        () => this.updateDB())
    }

    updateDB = debounce(() => {
        let data = {
            rateType: this.state.rateType
        };
        this.updateRateType(data);
    }, 1500);

    updateRateType(data) {
        fetch(API_URL + `/billingcalculator/project/update`, {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                projectId: this.props.billProjId,
                data: data,
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        })
            .then((res) => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    throw new Error();
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
            .then(this.renderAgain());
    }

    render() {
        return (
            
                <div>
                    <Jumbotron className="mt-3">
                        <h1 className='display-4'>Project: {this.props.projectName}</h1>
                        <p>Project ID:{this.props.billProjId}</p>
                        <Form>
                            <Form.Group
                                as={Row}
                                name="rateType"
                                controlId="rateType"
                                onChange={this.handleCheck}
                            >
                                <Form.Check
                                inline
                                label="profit"
                                name="rateType"
                                type="radio"
                                id="rateType-profit"
                                value="profit"
                                defaultChecked={this.state.rateType === "profit"}
                                />

                                <Form.Check
                                    inline
                                    label="non-profit"
                                    name="rateType"
                                    type="radio"
                                    id="rateType-non-profit"
                                    value="non-profit"
                                    defaultChecked={this.state.rateType === "non-profit"}
                                />
                                
                                <Form.Check
                                    inline
                                    label="existing-client"
                                    name="rateType"
                                    type="radio"
                                    id="rateType-existing"
                                    value="existing"
                                    defaultChecked={this.state.rateType === "existing"}
                                />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form>
                    </Jumbotron>
                </div>
            
        )
    }
}    


export default Project;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `checked` instead of `defaultChecked` if your checkbox is going to be updated after a component re-render

```
render() {
        return (
            
                <div>
                    <Jumbotron className="mt-3">
                        <h1 className='display-4'>Project: {this.props.projectName}</h1>
                        <p>Project ID:{this.props.billProjId}</p>
                        <Form>
                            <Form.Group
                                as={Row}
                                name="rateType"
                                controlId="rateType"
                                onChange={this.handleCheck}
                            >
                                <Form.Check
                                inline
                                label="profit"
                                name="rateType"
                                type="radio"
                                id="rateType-profit"
                                value="profit"
                                checked={this.state.rateType === "profit"}
                                />

                                <Form.Check
                                    inline
                                    label="non-profit"
                                    name="rateType"
                                    type="radio"
                                    id="rateType-non-profit"
                                    value="non-profit"
                                    checked={this.state.rateType === "non-profit"}
                                />
                                
                                <Form.Check
                                    inline
                                    label="existing-client"
                                    name="rateType"
                                    type="radio"
                                    id="rateType-existing"
                                    value="existing"
                                    checked={this.state.rateType === "existing"}
                                />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form>
                    </Jumbotron>
                </div>
            
        )
    }
```

Comment: That was it.  I knew it would be simple.   I hadn't seen where it says when you use checked vs defaultChecked.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: no worries! we learn everyday